# Window is invading wrong workspace when clicked on unity launcher icon

Tags: workspaces, window

I think this is a bug but will report this here before. There are 4 conditions to reproduce this problem:

1. you have a window open on one of the two bottom workspaces
2. this window is touching the top and bottom of your screen (but is not maximized)
3. you are on the workspace just above the one where the window is open
4. you click on the unity launcher of this application

Instead of bringing you down to the workspace where the window is open OR bringing the window up to the workspace where you are, what happens is that the window will shift down and partially invade the top workspace.

Additionally if you launch workspace switcher at this point and try dragging the window up to the workspace above the window will look as if it was behind the workspace (it will not appear on the workspace above)

Am I doing something wrong or is this really a bug?

Comment: This is actually a bug that is reported in [launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity/+bug/755842). Please go there and say it also affects you so that we can have this fixed on the next release.